# How to use powershell/c# to open the specific module in the application

Tags: c#, powershell

I wanted to open a module of the specific application.

For example, the application is abc.exe. And it is currently at Home Page.

And I wanted it to navigate to the page/module with title : Reporting modules,

What is the code can I use to navigate to the specific modules?

PowerShell can do it? If can't how about the c#?

Power shell code to navigate the specific module of the application.

Comment: You have a console application since you extension is exe.  Console application you only can entry the app at main.If you want to access other modules you need to add code to main that accepts the parameters in main and then depending on the options call other modules.See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line?force_isolation=true. Calling from windows the default entry point is main.  A exe can also be used the same a dll and you can call any public method for other modules provide the exe is referenced and there is a using statement.

Comment: I am not able to code the app, as it is the vendor's app. If power shell can not, is there any code to view id of the specific button (more accurate, it is a sub menu). Cause I don't know it's id and I know the click() need to use getElementbyID. 
If can, do you have the code to find the specific element by using the keyword and the code to click on the item??

Comment: You can only call methods that are public.  Only public items get put into the MAP and you need the start location from the MAP to be able to run the methods.  A dll and an exe are the same structure except the exe has extra code to run directly from windows (calls entry point main).  So a method in an exe can be called just like you would call a method in a dll.

Comment: So currently what I need to do is ask the developer what the method's name and it's state (private or public), right? Do I need to know others things in order for me to call it? And once I get the information, how can I call the method?

Comment: You need the methods, parameters list, and the return value for each method.  Methods that are public would show up in the map